# LogParser - Event log data value substitution

Tags: logparser

I'm not much of a scripting wiz and I have a small requirement to analyse the Windows security Event logs for firewall traffic.

To that end I've started looking at LogParser and it seems to do pretty much everything I need, but I'm having a little trouble working out how to substitute certain values extracted from the logs, into something more readable.

My script is very simple:

```
SELECT
TimeGenerated AS Time,
EventTypeName AS Event,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 0,'|') AS ProcessID,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 1,'|') AS Process,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 7,'|') AS Protocol,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 2,'|') AS Direction,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 3,'|') AS SourceAddress,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 4,'|') AS SourcePort,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 5,'|') AS DestinationAddress,
EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 6,'|') AS DestinationPort
FROM Security
WHERE EventID IN (5152; 5153; 5154; 5155; 5156; 5157; 5158)
```

Although this produces the information I'm interested in, I'd like, if possible, to change the output. For exampleThe 'Process' column output is:

\device\harddiskvolume2\apps\mozilla\fx-4\firefox.exe

What I'd really like is to just display the process name, without the path. Likewise the 'Protocol' column just displays the numeric protocol value. I prefer to have it display the 'actual' protocol.

Lastly, the Direction column displays a numerical value %%14592 and %%14593 and I'd prefer to see In and Out respectively.

If anyone can help, I'd be most grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your filename question, does the 
EXTRACT_FILENAME(EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 1,'|')) AS Process
work for you?

For your other other issue, how about:

CASE EXTRACT_TOKEN(Strings, 2,'|') WHEN '%%14592' THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END As Direction